# jmeter on macos stuck launching GUI

Tags: macos, jmeter

I am using latest `JMeter 5.2.1` on `Mojave 10.14.6`, I have both Java 8 and Java 11. I was able to use JMeter a few weeks ago and no idea why but it won't load the GUI. I look at `jmeter.log` and no errors it just looks something like this:

```
2019-12-02 16:35:37,880 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading user properties from: user.properties
2019-12-02 16:35:37,880 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading system properties from: system.properties
2019-12-02 16:35:37,887 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2018 The Apache Software Foundation
2019-12-02 16:35:37,887 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Version 5.0 r1840935
2019-12-02 16:35:37,887 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.version=11.0.5
2019-12-02 16:35:37,887 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.vm.name=OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
2019-12-02 16:35:37,887 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.name=Mac OS X
2019-12-02 16:35:37,887 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.arch=x86_64
2019-12-02 16:35:37,888 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.version=10.14.6
2019-12-02 16:35:37,888 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: file.encoding=UTF-8
2019-12-02 16:35:37,888 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Max memory     =4294967296
2019-12-02 16:35:37,888 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Available Processors =8
2019-12-02 16:35:37,899 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Default Locale=English (United States)
2019-12-02 16:35:37,899 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=English (United States)
2019-12-02 16:35:37,899 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: JMeterHome=/Users/xxx/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.0
2019-12-02 16:35:37,899 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: user.dir  =/Users/xxx/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.0/bin
2019-12-02 16:35:37,900 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: PWD       =/Users/xxx/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.0/bin
2019-12-02 16:35:37,967 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: IP: 10.100.24.66 Name: xxx-MAC3196 FullName: ixxx
```

after a few seconds it shows in activity manager that the process is unable to respond. I have tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it, restarting, checkout out source code from git and building it with gradle, installing another Java 8 and 11 from adoptopenjdk. Any way to debug this? logs have no error so not sure what else. Annoying thing is it worked like 2 weeks ago and I havent done anything with JMeter since.

Also, tried older JMeter versions 5.0 and 3.3 with both java 11 and 8, had various errors indicating it wouldn't work, so I went back to the latest versions.

Also, I was for some reason, not able to install using `brew install jmeter --with-plugins`, I think maybe it's because I updated brew awhile ago but not sure.. just keeps saying with plugin invalid options.

Comment: As I see from your log, you are trying to run JMeter v5.0 probably log for JMeter 5.2.1 will be different?

Answer (score 2):

Install JMeter with:

```
brew update 
brew install jmeter
```

Plugins should be already installed by default.

Run JMeter:

```
open /usr/local/bin/jmeter
```

Answer (score 1):

Please uninstall JDK 11, in fact, any version of JDK apart from JDK 8.
The latest versions of JDK are not stable. Hence, cannot be used mainstream.

Comment: In addition to this, Try installing JDK from the link below.
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: Is this a fact or just your opinion?

Comment: considering I tried 2 versions of java 8 and java 11 is there any reason you are saying its java related

Comment: JMeter works with java 8+, But this doesnt mean that  Java is stable. Oracle comes up with newer jdk every 6 months, this doesnt mean they are stable and can be used for mainstream purposes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history